# Android - How to change the default position of text and image in tabs?

Tags: android, image, text, android-tabs

Can we change the place of text and image in tabs?

Because images which i have used are slightly big in dimensions and hiding the title of my tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Changing Image and Text View in Tab Bar you need to write Custom Tab Bar.
Check this link for [Custom Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567532/android-ui-tabactivity-issue/5567823#5567823)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is increase the height of your tabs by calling `tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height`

**Eg.** In your main class which extends TabActivity, implement this code in your into your TabHost :

```
TabHost tabHost;


       for (int i = 0; i < getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++ ) {

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    }
```

Increase the height if it's not big enough for your custom image.
Happy coding!