# How can reduce the height of tab widget in android?

Tags: android

I am working in android. i want to reduce height of the tab widget. 
this is the image of my tab widget.
[image]

I have added my tab widget in the bottom, 0,1,2,3 etc.

i want to reduce the height of tabwidget then the displaying digits(0,1,2,3) disappears. this is my xml for the page.:-

whenver i reduce the size of height then content does not display.

please suggest me what should i do for this. 
Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height /=2;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

use this to specified in pixel

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 45, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
tab_widget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = (int)px;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Custom Tab for Customizing your Tab Bar.

Check my post for creating Custom tab Bar [Custom Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567532/android-ui-tabactivity-issue/5567823#5567823)