# how to reduce the tabsize in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-tablelayout, android-tabactivity

this is my tab it has extra some spaces i need to remove them. 
this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos");
       // photospec.setText("da");
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

       // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos");
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab

        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
}
```

i tried to change the size of the tab in layout like this

```
   <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:padding="0dip" />
```

if i do this text will be hidden.
[image]

when i reduce the height it becomes like this and text also hides
[image]

Comment: Why you use Deprecated TabActivity . Do use FragmentActivity instead TabActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height /=2; 
}
```

PS: I copy/paste it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645713/4224337)